# mapping jpa EJB failed

Tags: tomcat, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have EJB module Running in JBoss and a WEB module running in Tomcat.

I have implemented entities Remise and Voiture and I implemented interface VoitureRemote and the bean GestionVoiture implements VoitureRemote.

When i check to run the program without mapping it's running.

```
@Entity
public class Remise implements Serializable  {

    /**
     * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int nbnour;
    private float prix;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="voiture_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Voiture voiture;
```

And below is the entity Voiture:

```
@Entity
public class Voiture implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 15655L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String marque;
    private String reference;
    private String categorie;
    private int nbport;
    private int nbplace;
    private int nbcheveaux;
    private String Btevitesse;
    private Float prix;
    private String couleur;
    @Lob
    @Column(name="image", nullable=false, columnDefinition="mediumblob")
    private byte[] image;

    private boolean disponible;

    private Date date_pub;
    @OneToMany (mappedBy="voiture" , cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Remise> remise =new ArrayList<Remise>();
```

GestionVoiture implements VoitureRemote

```
@Stateless(mappedName="gvoiture")
public class GestionVoiture implements VoitureRemote {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Remise getRemise(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return em.find(Remise.class, id);
    }
}
```

In the web Module I have a servlet from doGet():

```
try {
    Context c;

    c = ContextFactory.getInstance().getContext();

    VoitureRemote vr=(VoitureRemote)c.lookup("gvoiture");

    Remise data=vr.getRemise(12);
    System.out.println(data.getVoiture().getMarque());

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The ContextFactory is a class to InitialContext with properties.

Below is the stack trace

```
    java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getRemise(Unknown Source)
    at controller.Tarifs.doGet(Tarifs.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.ClassLoaderUtility.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtility.java:103)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.RemotingClassLoader.loadClass(RemotingClassLoader.java:86)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting.loading.ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.resolveClass(ObjectInputStreamWithClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.InvocationResponse.readExternal(InvocationResponse.java:119)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObjectVersion2_2(JavaSerializationManager.java:238)
    at org.jboss.remoting.serialization.impl.java.JavaSerializationManager.receiveObject(JavaSerializationManager.java:138)
    at org.jboss.remoting.marshal.serializable.SerializableUnMarshaller.read(SerializableUnMarshaller.java:123)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.versionedRead(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1215)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:845)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:160)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1708)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:612)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getRemise(Unknown Source)
    at controller.Tarifs.doGet(Tarifs.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.session.SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionSpecProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:101)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: You need or to add the Hibernate jar to your web application, that's running on Tomcat, or to Tomcat itself, placing the jar on its *lib* folder.

Comment: The hibernate classes are being loaded by the servlet so it should be ok to just add the hibernate dependencies into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the web application.